# Ionic image src value is null

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I retrieved image location from firebase and also stored localstroage.

But first time i load my app the image src value is null

```
 <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title *ngIf="currentuser === '7'" class="text-center"><img id="logo" src="./assets/images/logo_black.png" alt="Smart Permises"></ion-title>
      <ion-title class="text-center">
         <h3>{{Apartmentname}}</h3>
        <img id="logo" [src]="logo" alt="Smart Permises" imageViewer/>
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

I checked the localstorage value .Its fine.why image src value is null.

```
  this.logo=localStorage.getItem('Logo');
  console.log(this.logo);
  this.Apartmentname=localStorage.getItem('Apartmentname');
  console.log(this.Apartmentname);
```

again i closedmy app.and opened .its work fine.

why?

Thanks

Comment: where you call this? `this.logo=localStorage.getItem('Logo');`. lifecycle event?

Comment: Thanks.I called constructor in app component.ts

Comment: Is an image in `app.html` file?

Comment: Ya.It's <img id="logo" [src]="logo" alt="Smart Permises" imageViewer/> app.html.

Comment: @Sampath.Can u help me...

Comment: you need to check firstly with the static url.is that work?

Answer (score 0):

`<img id="logo" src={{logo}} alt="Smart Permises" imageViewer />`

Putting it in `<img>` as `src={{_varName}}` has worked perfectly for me till now.

**Note:** Be sure that the url that you are getting does actually work. E.g. try `<img id="logo" src="<url>" alt="Smart Permises" imageViewer/>` where `<url>` is actually a resource.